# Grouping individuals by hash values in an array of hashes from user input and outputting names in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the below data structure in Ruby:

```
people = [
  { "name" => "John", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "pizza" },
  { "name" => "Joseph", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "burgers" },
  { "name" => "Lauren", "hobby" => "board games", "food" => "salads" } 
  { "name" => "Amir", "hobby" => "cycling", "food" => "burgers" },
  { "name" => "Mary", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "salads" },
  { "name" => "Karen", "hobby" => "board games", "food" => "pie" },
  { "name" => "Will", "hobby" => "cycling", "food" => "pizza" },
]
```

I need to write a program that will take in user input - either "hobby" or "food" and will then puts out a list of people grouped under subheadings for each hobby or food.

e.g. user inputs 'hobby' and a list is puts'ed to the console similar to the below:

tennis
John
Joseph
Mary
board games
Lauren
Karen
cycling
Amir
Will

So far I have got as far as being able to generate a new array that has the hobbies and the names, however they are seperate and I'm not sure if it's the best way of going around getting the category name with a list of people underneath... also there are a few nil values being pulled out too e.g. below:

```
    puts "Enter what category to search"
    category = gets.chomp

    grouped_data = people.group_by { |x| x[category] }
    new_array = []
    grouped_data.each { |n| new_array.push n[0] }
    grouped_data.flatten.flatten.each { |n| new_array.push n["name"] }

    p new_array
```

With input "hobby" gives me an array:

```
    ["tennis", "board games", "cycling", nil, "John", "Joseph", "Mary", nil, "Lauren", "Karen", nil, "Amir", "Will"]
```

Am I on the right track? Is there another avenue worth exploring?

Thanks! Hope this has been laid out alright as it's first time posting on SA.

Comment: the line with "Lauren" is missing a comma.

Comment: `grouped_data.each { |n| new_array.push n[0] }` is an elaborate way of writing `grouped_data.keys`

Comment: You have flatten the grouped_data into an array looking like ["tennis", {a_hash}, {another_hash}...] and proceed to try to get the `["name"]`. `"tennis"["name"]` is valid syntax. it will result in `nil` because the word "name" is not found in "tennis".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track by using [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) since it gets you a hash where the keys are the "category" and the values are an array of "persons" that fit that "category".  What I think you want to do next is use [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) along with [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) to map each person into just thier name.

```rb
people = [
  { "name" => "John", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "pizza" },
  { "name" => "Joseph", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "burgers" },
  { "name" => "Lauren", "hobby" => "board games", "food" => "salads" } ,
  { "name" => "Amir", "hobby" => "cycling", "food" => "burgers" },
  { "name" => "Mary", "hobby" => "tennis", "food" => "salads" },
  { "name" => "Karen", "hobby" => "board games", "food" => "pie" },
  { "name" => "Will", "hobby" => "cycling", "food" => "pizza" },
]

by_category = people.group_by {|category| category["hobby"]}
    .transform_values {|value| value.map{ |person| person["name"]}}
p by_category
```

Which produces:

```rb
{"tennis"=>["John", "Joseph", "Mary"], "board games"=>["Lauren", "Karen"], "cycling"=>["Amir", "Will"]}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, just had to flatten the final outcome and 'puts' rather than 'print' to get the list in the correct format for what I was doing.

Many thanks! Always makes so much sense suddenly when you get to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what each step of your code returns. Assuming `category` is `'hobby'`.

```
grouped_data = people.group_by { |x| x[category] }
# => {"tennis"=>[{"name"=>"John", "hobby"=>"tennis", "food"=>"pizza"}, 
#                {"name"=>"Joseph", "hobby"=>"tennis", "ood"=>"burgers"}, 
#                {"name"=>"Mary", "hobby"=>"tennis", "food"=>"salads"}], 
#     "board games"=>[{"name"=>"Lauren", "hobby"=>"board games", "food"=>"salads"}, 
#                     {"name"=>"Karen", "hobby"=>"board games", "food"=>"pie"}], 
#     "cycling"=>[{"name"=>"Amir", "hobby"=>"cycling", "food"=>"burgers"}, 
#                 {"name"=>"Will", "hobby"=>"cycling", "food"=>"pizza"}]}
```

Now:

```
new_array = []
grouped_data.each { |n| new_array.push n[0] }
new_array
# 
=> ["tennis", "board games", "cycling"]
```

Then:

```
grouped_data.flatten.flatten.each { |n| new_array.push n["name"] }
new_array
# => ["tennis", "board games", "cycling", nil, "John", "Joseph", "Mary", nil, "Lauren", "Karen", nil, "Amir", "Will"]
```

If we look at just:

```
grouped_data.flatten.flatten
# => ["tennis", 
#     {"name"=>"John", "hobby"=>"tennis", "food"=>"pizza"}, 
#     {"name"=>"Joseph", "hobby"=>"tennis", "food"=>"burgers"},
#      {"name"=>"Mary", "hobby"=>"tennis", "food"=>"salads"}, 
#     "board games", 
#     {"name"=>"Lauren", "hobby"=>"board games", "food"=>"salads"},
#      {"name"=>"Karen", "hobby"=>"board games", "food"=>"pie"}, 
#     "cycling", {"name"=>"Amir", "hobby"=>"cycling", 
#     "food"=>"burgers"}, {"name"=>"Will", "hobby"=>"cycling",
#      "food"=>"pizza"}]
```

This was not a particularly useful data structure to iterate over.

You were on the right track with `#group_by` and the resulting data structure you got, you just needed to transform the values from an array of hashes into an array of names.

### Alternatively...

A little more directly, grouping by hobby without creating unnecessary intermediate objects.

```
by_hobbies = people.each_with_object({}) do |person, hsh|
  hobby = person["hobby"]
  hsh[hobby] ||= []
  hsh[hobby] << person["name"]
end

p by_hobbies
```

Output:

```
{"tennis"=>["John", "Joseph", "Mary"], "board games"=>["Lauren", "Karen"], "cycling"=>["Amir", "Will"]}
```